# How to handle error with react-query, without triggering "unhandledrejection" event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I'm using `onError` callback funtion in useMutation. It is only triggered, when `foo()` throws.

```
const mutation = useMutation({
   mutationFn: foo(),
   onError: () => {
      console.log("error caught by onError");
   }
})
```

I also have a listener on unhandledrejection event, that triggers whenever a promise is rejected

```
window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", (e) => {
   console.log("error caught by window");
})
```

when `foo()` throws, both logs are visible in the console. Is it possible to trigger only `onError` callback, without triggering "unhandledrejection" event?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be stupid mistake from me, `mutation.mutate` instead of `mutation.mutateAsync`solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You could simple use `catch` directly on the `foo()`:

```
const mutation = useMutation({
   mutationFn: foo().catch(e => console.log("error caught by onError")),
 
})
```

Comment: This approach unfortunately triggers onSuccess callback